# Has anyone done training on custom data using AllenNLP for coreference resolution?

Tags: nlp, training-data, allennlp, custom-training, coreference-resolution

I'm trying to train AllenNLP on custom data instead of using the pre-trained model for coreference resolution. The instructions are [here](https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution) but they are very vague and I am not sure how to progress, in particular I don't know how to modify the JSONNET file to indicate the path to my train, test and dev ConLL-2012 training files. Has anyone ever accomplished this before? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path to your data in these lines in the jsonnet config:

```
  "train_data_path": std.extVar("COREF_TRAIN_DATA_PATH"),
  "validation_data_path": std.extVar("COREF_DEV_DATA_PATH"),
  "test_data_path": std.extVar("COREF_TEST_DATA_PATH"),
```

Either you can update the config to use your paths explicitly, or else set these environment variables before running the config with the `allennlp train` command.